# I can't find the format error in Azure Pipeline yaml

Tags: yaml, format, azure-pipelines

I have an azure pipeline yml, I added some conditionals but now I'm getting errors messages in two conditionals

When I run the pipeline I get this error message:
*/build-pipeline.yml (Line: 208, Col: 9): While parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key.*

After that I installed prettier and in VScode it shjows me the next error messages:

*A block sequence may not be used as an implicit map keyYAML
Implicit keys need to be on a single lineYAML
Implicit map keys need to be followed by map valuesYAML*

The code in the two conditionals is the same since is the same code but executed in different parts of the pipeline.

The error that I get is in the first conditional - ${{ if eq(variables.isQa, true) }}:  that checks if the environment is QA but I'm guessing that the whole code is badly formatted

```
    - task: Docker@0
      displayName: 'Build an image'
      inputs:
        command: 'buildAndPush'
        - ${{ if eq(variables.isQa, true) }}: 
            buildContext: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/enext-data-platform-backend/
        - ${{ if eq(variables.isDev, true) }}: 
            buildContext: enext-data-platform-backend
        containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
        imageName: "$(Build.Repository.Name):$(Build.BuildId)"
        - ${{ if eq(variables.isQa, true) }}: 
          Dockerfile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/enext-data-platform-backend/Dockerfile
        - ${{ if eq(variables.isDev, true) }}:
          Dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'
```

This exact part of code is executed in another part of the pipeline and I'm getting the same error in the same conditional.

I've tried acommodating the spaces a bunch of times and also modifying the conditionals, but since I'm new working with yaml files I know I'm missing something, This is the only part of the pipeline where I get the error, in other conditionals that I added are working fine, I can upload all of the pipeline code if you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be some misunderstandinds to use the `docker` task  syntax. For `docker@0` task, we cannot use the property of `buildContext` and it should be used `docker@1` or `docker@2` instead. See the syntax differences in  [Docker@0 - Docker v0 task | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/docker-v0?view=azure-pipelines), [Docker@1 - Docker v1 task | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/docker-v1?view=azure-pipelines) and [Docker@2 - Docker v2 task | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/docker-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml).

Here is a modified YAML for your reference, where the conditional insertions begin with no dash `-` to infer sequence. Since you have been evaluating the values of two variables `isQa` and `isDev`, please make sure their values are not set as `true` **at the same time** and you may also consider using `${elseif}` expressions to have the condtion `eq(variables.isDev, true)` only work when `nq(variables.isQa, true)` (see [Conditional insertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion) for more information).

```
steps:
- task: Docker@1
  displayName: 'Build an image'
  inputs:
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    ${{ if eq(variables.isQa, true) }}: 
      buildContext: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/enext-data-platform-backend/
    ${{ elseif eq(variables.isDev, true) }}: 
      buildContext: enext-data-platform-backend
    containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
    imageName: "$(Build.Repository.Name):$(Build.BuildId)"
    ${{ if eq(variables.isQa, true) }}: 
      Dockerfile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/enext-data-platform-backend/Dockerfile
    ${{ elseif eq(variables.isDev, true) }}:
      Dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'
```

In addition, kindly be also advised to use the `Validate` function of a pipeline editor to check and locate syntax errors.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your provided .yaml:

---

### #1 Formatting issues

- You do not need to add a `-` before the `${{ if ... }}` expression.
- Your spacing is inconsistent
- Make sure that you are using `if` / `elseif` / `else` for the same input so that the pipeline does not somehow run into a state where it is trying to define the same input multiple times.

Here is an example `.yaml` snippet on how you can use expressions to conditionally set inputs that I have tested locally and works:

```
variables:
- name: isQa
  value: false

jobs:
- job:
  steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: Print all variables
      inputs:
        targetType: "inline"
        ${{ if eq(variables.isQa, true) }}: 
          script: Write-Host "Is QA"
        ${{ elseif eq(variables.isQa, false) }}: 
          script: Write-Host "Not QA"
```

Here is what your example snippit looks like with these changes applied:

```
steps:
- task: Docker@1
  displayName: 'Build an image'
  inputs:
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
    imageName: "$(Build.Repository.Name):$(Build.BuildId)"
    ${{ if eq(variables.isQa, true) }}: 
      buildContext: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/enext-data-platform-backend/
    ${{ elseif eq(variables.isDev, true) }}: 
      buildContext: enext-data-platform-backend
    ${{ if eq(variables.isQa, true) }}: 
      dockerfile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/enext-data-platform-backend/Dockerfile
    ${{ elseif eq(variables.isDev, true) }}:
      dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'
```

---

### #2 Incorrect usage of inputs

You are mixing inputs from the `Docker@0` and `Docker@2` tasks.

- `containerregistrytype` is only valid in `Docker@0`
- `imageName` is only valid in `Docker@0`
- `command` is only valid in `Docker@2`
- `buildContext` is only valid in `Docker@2`
- `dockerfile` is valid in both `Docker@0` and `Docker@2`

Since you are using `Docker@0`, you should only be using inputs available in that version. If you wish to instead use `Docker@2`, you will need to update your yaml, and make sure you are only using the available inputs for that version. See docs for each here:

- [Docker@0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/docker-v0?view=azure-pipelines)
- [Docker@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/docker-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml)